# Spit max entity from query

Tags: google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

How do I get max model given parameter from query?

What i want is get xs parameter, compare xs max in ndb.

If max_ndb(xs) is higher return the max_model, otherwise return 204

```
   @MyModel.query_method(requests_fields('xs',),
                               name='infofest',
                               path='mymodel',
                               http_method='GET'
                               )
    def get_model(self,query):
        return max(query, key=MyModel.xs)#??
```

Of course query itself is not iterable,and i may not use query_method instead,
Something like.

```
@MyModel.method(request_fields=('xs',),
                  path='mymodel/{xs}', http_method='GET', name='mymodel.get')   def MyModelGet(self, my_model):
     if not my_model.maxXS_from_datastore:
        return model_with_maxXS
     return 204
```

Or can we use GQL in endpoints-proto-datastore? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is "grabbing the max xs from datastore", it is not doable directly, but it can be easily achieved by using a sort on your query, and taking the first result.

Something like (this is more/less pseudo code, I never used python's ndb, I usually work with java's objectify, but the logic is the same) :

myModel.query().sort("xs descending");

At this point, the first result of that query will simply be your highest "xs" object. You can do your comparison on that first object.

Comment: Thanks i've been doing that, and have list of descending order.
Is this query iterable? i always get
'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetch_page''

Comment: I don't think you need to fetch the whole page, you should grab the first item in the returned list from the query, no?

Comment: myModel.query().fetch(1) give me the error i mentioned, did i understand it wrong?